# Div split vertically, with right side scrollable horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how I can split a div vertically such that there's a left and right side. Suppose that I want the right side to be configured such that I can scroll horizontally on it.

I have attached an image to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

My code is something like this:

```
<div class='container'>

    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right></div>

</div>
```

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 80rem;
    }

    .right {
        width: 60rem;
        overflow-x: scroll;
    }
    
    .left {
        width: 40rem; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved by creating a container, which will make active the horizontal overflow.

```css
  .container {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .right {
      width: 60%;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      background: blue;
      height: 100vh;
  }

  .left {
      width: 40%; 
      background: yellow;
      height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .moving-content {
    width: 200vw;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>

    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right'>
      <div class="moving-content">
        horizontal scroll
      </div>
        
    </div>

</div>
```